# How to retreive data from firestore flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new into flutter and firebase integrations and I'm having some troubles to retreive all the data from the firebase collection.

I have tried this method:

```dart
    getCollection() {
      CollectionReference coleccion =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('materias');
      return Container(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: coleccion.doc('aprobadas').snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
              return Text(snapshot.data.data()['codigo'],
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color: Colors.white));
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ),
      );
    }
```

Now I'm a little bit frustrated because I have tried a differents methods and doesn't work.

I really appreciate all the help.

Best regards

Comment: What is the error you get / What is the problem you're facing with this method?

Comment: The snapshot data was null and the circular progress indicator get stuck, I review the data on the firebase console and there is the data I need to show

Comment: What happens if you use `snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState,done`?

Answer (score 0):

Data can be retrieved using the below code from firestore to flutter.

**One-time Read**

call the `Query.get` or `DocumentReference.get` methods

```
class GetUserName extends StatelessWidget {
  final String documentId;

  GetUserName(this.documentId);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
      builder:
      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
          return Text("Document does not exist");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text("Full Name: ${data['full_name']}         ${data['last_name']}");
        }

        return Text("loading");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Realtime changes**

FlutterFire provides support for dealing with real-time changes to collections and documents. A new event is provided on the initial request, and any subsequent changes to collection/document whenever a change occurs (modification, deleted or added).

Both the `CollectionReference` & `DocumentReference` provide a snapshots() method which returns a Stream:

```
Stream collectionStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();
Stream documentStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('ABC123').snapshots();
```

Please refer official documentation [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#read-data)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StreamBuilder`. That will be easy to understand.

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("collection").snapshot,
    builder: (BuildContext context,snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasdata!=true) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
        } else {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemcount:snapshot.data.docs.length,
                builder(context,index) {
                return Text(snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["filedname"]);
        }
    }
)
```